# Codeigniter “The requested URL was not found” error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I downloaded project the my server then I changed config file and database as usually and finally i deleted the htaccess file that is in the main folder. Now i can go to my home page but i can't go to other links in my site and i got this error.

```
**Not Found
    The requested URL /utripes/auther/signup signup was not found on this server.**
```

How can i fix this error.
please need quick help. than you.

Comment: I have already answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062142/why-codeigniter-show-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server/41862237#41862237

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As you delete the htaccess file from your project root directory so your url should include index.php.

I recommend that you include the htaccess file in your project root directory and paste the following code into the htaccess file..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

I think now your project should work fine..

Comment: when i do that i got this 
"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log" In the error log has ".htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration" that's why i delete the .htaccess file

Comment: ok fine. then check that your mod_rewrite module is on or off??
If off then on the mod_rewrite module.
after enable the mod_rewrite module you have to restart wamp and
hope problem will be gone

Comment: Than you for your help

Comment: answered this type of problem here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062142/why-codeigniter-show-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server/41862237#41862237

Answer (score 3):

your rewrite rule should be like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /your_project/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>


    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, but I moved my site from another server to current and in the process, uploaded all files to google drive and downloaded to current server, that changed names of all .* files to _*

I changed all names back to .* and was able to connect to subsequent pages of my codeigniter website.