# Why codeIgniter show the requested URL was not found on this server?

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, url, debian

I want to ask. First of all, I will tell that I've develop an application use codeIgniter on my windows dekstop. And it clear and run completely.

But, after I move that project to debian server, it said :

```
The requested URL /index.php/Admin was not found on this server.
```

I want to ask, why I got an output like that? Eventhough I ran the same project with the same code. How can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you done enough routing configuration for your application

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: First check `$config['base_url']` and `.htaccess` file values.

Answer (score 13):

First of all enable mod_rewrite then restart apache2 using following commands:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

then open apache conf file using command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

uncomment below line if it is commented

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

then find these lines in apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```

here change the line AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All and save this file.

Now, your issue is resolved.

Comment: Been trying to figure out with a site without Codeigniter worked and another with Codeigniter didn't, and your answer solved the problem! Thank you so much! +1

Comment: @JuOliveira Glad, it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Codelgniter URL example :

```
example.com/class/function/id/
```

So check your class name correct or not, And call url instead of Capital A - Admin to admin.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller 
{

}
```

Note: if you use codelgniter-3 version file name also must Should capital A. I mean Admin.php

Comment: I think the code is correct, because I also hosting it to another debian server and it's clear. But why in this server, I got output like that? I think that there is something about server configuration, do you know?

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you should know the `debian` is a Linux base server. So Its not like windows servers(XAMPP and WAMP).

So first of all consider about Letters. It means **debian Sever is Case-Sensitive**.

So **check your naming conversation as well**

Check these

1. Controller class name `class Admin extends CI_Controller`
2. Controller file name should be `admin.php`
3. Check in `routes.php`. In routes `$route['default_controller'] = "admin";`

Comment: Controller file name should be Admin.php upper case in codeigniter 3

Comment: @wolfgang1983 there is no harm with file name

Comment: But that is what I have been told by the developers of codeigniter 3 because of some live servers. Works fine on localhost with lower case but when go to live that when may have issue.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 But i check. Its work with no harm still. Some how you may be correct

Comment: See http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names "Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries, drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner"

Comment: @kenjis thanks for link. How ever OP question related to CI 2

Answer (score 0):

after long searched I got the problem
enable .htaccess file in apache by going
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
than search  /var/www/html in that file
after you got that line change  AllowOverride None To All

for further information
https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/enable-mod_rewrite-apache-centos/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31929834)