# In codeigniter 3 requested url was not found error on ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm facing error **requested URL not found** in codeigniter 3. I tried lot of stuffs to get rid of this issue but didn't success. I think i have issues with my .htaccess file.
Here is content of .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062142/why-codeigniter-show-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server/41862237#41862237

Comment: it worked for me. thanks. @Avnishalok